# Link External JavaScript File to Polymer Element

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend

I am working on implementing an autocomplete feature for a polymer element. I would like to add a reference to a trie.js file that contains a ready-to-use implementation of a trie (from https://github.com/mikedeboer/trie/blob/master/trie.js). I have looked online for answers and found some links such as [How to include external script files for publishing custom Polymer element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951777/how-to-include-external-script-files-for-publishing-custom-polymer-element) and [Polymer element with javascript dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135095/polymer-element-with-javascript-dependencies)  However, so far I have not found a satisfactory answer. My approach so far is

```
<link href="../../Scripts/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import" />
<link href="../../Scripts/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import" />
<link href="../../Scripts/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import" />

<dom-module id="my-select">
    <link href="my-select.css" rel="import" type="css" />
    <template>...
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script src="trie.js"></script>
<script src="my-select.js"></script>
```

However, it is not working yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That is the correct way to import and external js file. Here's an [example of it working](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhRmMHehnj5zip0BpANw).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @KevinAshcraft!